# Why Android Studio sort Java class instance variable order by alphabet automatically?

Tags: java, android

I have a Java class named Test.TestInfo like below:

```
public class Test {
    public static class TestInfo {
        public int a;  // 1st class variable
        public int c;  // 2nd class variable
        public int b;  // 3rd class variable

        public TestInfo() {
            this(0, 0, 0);
        }
        public TestInfo(
                int a,
                int c,
                int b
                ) {
            this.a = a;
            this.c = c;
            this.b = b;
        }
    }
}
```

Then I try to initial class in Java and print the class. Code like below:

```
Test.TestInfo testInfo = new Test.TestInfo(1,3,2);
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().serializeNulls().create();
System.out.println(gson.toJson(testInfo));
```

I get two different order of class variable in Java unit test and Android instrumented test:

Java unit test

```
{
  "a": 1,
  "c": 3,
  "b": 2
}
```

Android instrumented test

```
{
  "a": 1,
  "b": 2,
  "c": 3
}
```

I want fixed class variable order like Java Unit Test result (what I definition in class), but in Android it seems sort my class variable by alphabet, I have no idea which part I missed. Can anybody help me out?

Comment: Fields in a JSON object are unordered. If you want to compare them, use a suitable library to compare/assert JSON objects to take into account the fact that this is unordered.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I think it's not json problem. Cause I have an encode/decode function that will encode/decode class instance variable by order in for loop. In Java Unit Test it will encode/decode like a>c>b, but when I run it on Android it will encode/decode by a>b>c which isn't a correct output. But still thanks for your reply, this problem still confusing me tho.

Comment: I don't know your build setup, but it's possible that you've configured some obfuscation. That tends to rewrite classes and might change the order of fields. Generally speaking, I'd try to avoid depending on the order of fields in a class since [`Class.getDeclaredFields()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredFields()) doesn't actually guarantee that you get them in any specific order (such as source-file order). If you need some order, it's better to provide that via annotations or just define some based on the names.